# Getting Current span element having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam having multiple span elements with same class name that were created dynamically.

```
<span class="btn catgry" style="margin:10px" onclick="catg()">'+result[i]+'</span>'
```

How to get the current span elements text that was clicked. i had tried this

```
function catg()
{
--
var s = $(".catgry",this) .text();
--
}
```

but its not working ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to *pass* current element using `this` keyword:

```
... onclick="catg(this);" ...
```

And catch it in JavaScript with:

```
function catg(span) {
    ...
    var s = $(span).text();
    ...
}
```

Another option is to bind click event omitting `onclick` attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn.catgry", function() {
    ...
    var s = $(this).text();
    ...
});
```

Here instead of `document` you can use any *static* parent element of `.btn.catgry`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function clicked(evt) { 
    alert(evt.target.textContent);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");

    span.className = "btn catgry";
    span.textContent = "Result" + i;
    span.addEventListener("click", clicked, false);
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/DXAeC/)

The use of inline javascript is considered bad practice.

i.e `onclick="catg()"`

If you are going to use jquery to add events after you dynamically add your spans. Then consider using [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

```
function clicked(evt) { 
    alert(evt.target.textContent);
}

$(document).on("click", ".btn", clicked);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    var span = $("<span>").attr({
        "class":  "btn catgry"
    }).text("Result" + i);

    $(document.body).append(span);
}
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jagnP/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try

```
var spanText = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

y don't u use like this

```
$('span.catgry').click(function(){
   //your logic
   var text = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if they arecreated dinamicaly i suggest you to wrap the spans in a wrapper to let jquery to get spans created after dom ready

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.catgry', function(){
var s = $(this).text();
})
```